# IndexError: list assignment index out of range.. Can't find mistake in the code

Tags: python, python-3.x

guys. I can't find mistake in code.. Help me please)

```
 x = [2]
 y = [2]
 z = [2]


x[0] = int(random.randint(xmin, int((2 * xmax - xmin) / 2)))
y[0] = int(random.randint(xmin, int((2 * ymax - xmin) / 2)))
z[0] = int(random.randint(xmin, int((2 * zmax - xmin) / 2)))    

def Fxyz(self):
    return ((y[0]**2)*(y[0]*z) + (x[0]*y[0] + 2*y[0])*(y[0]**3))
def fx(self):
    return y[0]**4
def fy(self):
    return (3*(y[0]**2)*z[0] + 11*(y[0]**1))
def fz(self):
    return y[0]**3

print("Start x = " + str(x[0]))
print("y = " + str(y[0]))
print("z = " + str(z[0]))

print("Choosе:\n\t1) Find min\n\t2) Find max\n\t3) End program")
choice = int(input())
if choice == 3:
    pass
elif choice == 1:
    while (True):
        x[1] = x[0] - h * fx(y[0])
        y[1] = y[0] - h * fy(y[0], z[0])
        z[1] = z[0] - h * fz(y[0])
```

I can't find mistake, googled every possible forum etc.. Help please.

Error from console:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Рабочий стол\#PROJECTS\Programming\яп\лаба 2\lab2.py", line 44, in <module>
    x[1] = x[0] - h * fx(y[0])
IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

Comment: You assign something to `x[1]` but `x[1]` doesn't exist. Your list has only one element with index `0`. Are you looking for the lists `append` method?

Comment: `x`, `y`, and `z` are all single item lists.  You reference that item with an index of `0`.  Assigning to `x[1]` is beyond the end of `x`.  You could append to `x` to get a second element or you could create your list with an initial length of two as in `x = [2, None]`.

Comment: Your code has further bugs.  Your functions have a `self` argument but aren't part of a class.  (If they are part of a class that's fine.)  Another problem is the use of globals.  it would be better to explicitly pass your variables as arguments.  You seem to do that when you call the functions, but the value is assigned to `self` and you never use `self` in the body of the function.

Comment: I added None item to x, y, z. But there is another error..
fy() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given